# dynamic product promotion

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My goal: I want to make my life as a email manager much easier. Therefore I want to build a content area that can generate a product-promotion out of an identifier (e.g. product_id) by having that identifier in another Data Extension. The product-promotion shall contain a product – picture, -price, -name and link to the detail page.

Unfortunatly the structure of the data extension isn´t the best because I don´t have an unique identifier.

That means taking an input_ID and comparing it with field “product_Id” in the product DE. To compare it I need to ignore the first and the last 3 positions of the “product_id”.

Then I´m gonna have e.g. 10 matches because every size has it´s own row. Which row isn´t important for me. Now I want to put the value from “itemname” into the mail.

```
Inputvalue of the Briefing DE:         023101
 Product_id of the product DE:      000023101140
                      compare:      000**023101**140
```

Does anybody has an idea to start that AMP? I tried it with substring etc. but I didn’t work. I would like to show my own tryouts but it is only BS.

Comment: I don't know how often your product DE is updated, but you could run an automation with a query activity, updating an additional column containing a substring of Product_id, which you can use for mapping.

Comment: @LukasLunow it runs once a day. I was hoping to avoid duplicate the whole DE or is there a possibilty to add that column to the existing DE?

Comment: @LukasLunow: okay. You had suggested exactly that. Sry. Do you see another way without touching the DE?

Comment: just to verify,  Briefing InputValue is a unique 'substring' of product_id, but it can return many full product_id rows from Product DE? And that you don't care which one of these rows is selected of those as each will provide the same values you need for your content area?

Comment: @Gortonington exactly

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing inside of AMPScript that can do this without Looping through all of the Product_id DE and using conditionals in that. Which is very inefficient and time consuming.

You could use the SSJS CORE function of Rows.Retrieve with a filter to get it, but this is likely to be even less performant and shouldn't be used in a sending context.

What I would do is a SQL Join, every X time period (I would recommend daily, but can be up to hourly if you need it to be.) to create a connector DE for you to pull product_Ids, etc from.

For example:

```
SELECT
  a.BriefingID,
  b.Product_ID,
  b.Picture,
  b.Price,
  b.Name,
  b.Link
FROM
  DE1 a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUBSTRING(Product_ID, 4, 6) as BriefingID,
      Product_ID,
      Picture,
      Price,
      Name,
      Link
    FROM
      DE2
  ) b ON b.BriefingID = a.BriefingID
```

This will then write to DE3 which is where you will lookup by BriefingID to get your picture,name, etc. fields.

You will want to do a LookupOrderedRows() function and have it set to return just a single row.

Example:

`LookUpOrderedRows('DE3', 1, 'BriefingID ASC', 'BriefingID', @BriefingID)`

**Please note that this is reliant on your Product_ID containg the same amount of characters for every single one.**